# Call to undefined method App\Product::whereHas() in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi try to get my products list in subcategory page but i'm getting this error

> Call to undefined method App\Product::whereHas()

here is my function

```
// Subategory page included posts
    public function productsubcategory($slug)
    {
       $products = Product::whereHas('subcategory.category', function($q) use($slug){
       $q->where('slug',$slug);
       })->paginate(6);
        return view('frontend.subcategories', compact('products'));
    }
```

this is my route:

```
Route::get('/category/{slug}/subcategory/{subslug}', ['as' => 'showbysub', 'uses' => 'IndexController@productsubcategory']);
```

my product model:

```
public function categories(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
  }

  public function subcategories(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Subcategory::class);
  }
```

category model:

```
public function products(){
     return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
  }

  public function subcategories(){
     return $this->hasMany(Subcategory::class);
  }
```

subcategory model:

```
public function category(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
  }

  public function products(){
     return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
  }
```

any idea?

**UPDATE:**

I changed my function to:

```
public function productsubcategory($slug)
    {
        $subcategories = Subcategory::where('slug','=',$slug)->with('products')->paginate(6);
        return view('frontend.subcategories', compact('subcategories'));
    }
```

and now my page is loading but will not show any item (product).

## UPDATE 2

I changed my function to this:

```
public function productsubcategory($slug)
    {
        $products = Product::with('subcategories')
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->get();
        return view('frontend.subcategories', compact('products'));
    }
```

> Now I can get products but the problem is all products will show even
> if they're included other categories.

How to solve that?

Comment: Is your `Product` class extending the base `Model` class? Show your model definition.

Comment: You had used two slugs in your route and taking only one in your controller.
What is dis i didn't understand.

Comment: @rits it will return url like: `url/category/xx/subcategory/xxxx/`

Comment: yup that is ok but i am just trying to say is you are passing two slugs in your route but using only one into your controller, why?

Comment: Before i used two slug such as `$slug, $subslug` but i found with only one slug it works also cause i only try to get products in subcategory and not subcategory list under categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

```
public function productsubcategory($slug, $subslug)
    {
        $products = Product::whereHas('subcategory', function($q) use($subslug){
        $q->where('slug',$subslug);
        })->get();
        return view('frontend.subcategories', compact('products'));
    }
```

and product model from `subcategories` change to `subcategory`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what do you mean in this lines

```
$products = Product::whereHas('subcategory.category', function($q) use($slug){
    $q->where('slug',$slug);
})->paginate(6);
```

Refer to https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships. If you are trying to querying relationship, you can do like this:

```
$products = Product::whereHas('subcategories', function($q) use($slug){
    $q->where('slug',$slug);
})->paginate(6);
```

or

```
$products = Product::whereHas('categories', function($q) use($slug){
    $q->where('slug',$slug);
})->paginate(6);
```

The relationship name must the same with relationship method in your `Product` model

Comment: i get this error  `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.subcategories_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `products` where exists (select * from `subcategories` where `products`.`subcategories_id` = `subcategories`.`id` and `slug` = handphone))`